# include soft deleted models in yajra/laravel-datatables results on change status of a checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatable

I am using [yajra/laravel-datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) laravel package to show a list of all records of a Model.

Now I want to include soft deleted models in the result by changing a simple checkbox.

this is my checkbox :

```
<input class="checked-switch" type="checkbox" id="showDeleted" />
```

and this is my datatable jquery code to send and retrieve result :

```
$('#allCoursesTable').DataTable({
                    processing: true,
                    serverSide: true,
                    "bSort": false,
                    "responsive": true,
                    ajax: {
                        url :   '{!! route('coursesData') !!}',
                        data: function(d){
                            d.showDeleted =   $('#showDeleted').prop('checked')
                        }
                    },
                    columns: [
                        //columns properties come here
                    ]
                });

        $('#showDeleted').change(function (e) {
            console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
            allCoursesTable.draw();
        });
```

And in the backend I write this :

```
public function coursesData (Request $request)
    {
        $courses =
            Course::select(['course_id', 'title', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'picture', 'lesson_count', 'status', 'active', 'teacher','start_date','end_date','reg_start_date','reg_end_date']);


        if ($request->get('showDeleted')) {
            //what Can I do here???
        }

        $datatable = app('datatables')->of($courses)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')

        // add Or edit columns come here

        return $datatable->make(true);
    }
```

I know that to include soft deleted models in pure laravel should do this :

```
$Courses= App\Course::withTrashed()->get();
```

But I do not know how add or remove `withTrashed()` method based on checkbox state.

How Can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [bobbybouwmann answer at laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/include-soft-deleted-models-in-yajralaravel-datatables-results-on-change-status-of-a-checkbox/replies/157616), solution is :

```
    $courses = Course::select(['course_id', 'title', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'picture', 'lesson_count', 'status', 'active', 'teacher','start_date','end_date','reg_start_date','reg_end_date']);

// It depends on what you pass through, but I would pass 1 or something.
if ($request->has('checkbox_field') && $request->get('checkbox_field') == 1) {
    $courses = $courses->withTrashed();
}


$datatable = app('datatables')
    ->of($courses)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
```

and in the javascript codes :

```
data: function(d){
    d.showDeleted =   $('#showDeleted').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Now I thing work fine.